# Usage of "compared to"

Tags: comparison, comparative-constructions, comparative, comparative-degree

Which can I say?

> The price of A is higher compared to **B**.

or

> The price of A is higher compared to **the price of B**.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and write two complete sentences so that we can clearly see what you are trying to express? Also, it might be helpful if you provide your own thoughts so that users can address your specific confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price of A is higher compared to B

The price of A is higher compared to the price of B.

The former is not grammatical. You  want to compare the price of A to the price of B, not the price of A to the thing B. So the latter is grammatical.

However, to avoid the repetition of the phrase "the price of",  you can use "that of" as follows:

The price of A is higher compared to that of B.

Moreover, it's more idiomatic and common to use the positive degree instead of the comparative degree of an adjective in front of compared to/with as follows:

The price of A is high compared to that of B.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, **'B'** and **'the price of B'** can be used interchangeably in this sentence, as it is implicit in the sentence that we are comparing the prices of A and B.

However, while I can't say it's gramatically incorrect, there seems to be redundancy in your sentence with the usage of 'higher compared to'.

'higher' is already a comparative, therefore the sentence structure **'*comparative* compared to'** seems like unnecessary duplication, and grates with me somewhat as a native speaker.

Personally, I wouldn't structure a sentence with two comparatives, I'd instead use one of the following constructions:

- The price of A is high compared to B.
- The price of A is high compared to the price of B.
- The price of A is higher than B.
- The price of A is higher than the price of B.